# Simple chess engine in Python

Tags: python, performance, chess

I have programmed a chess AI in python as a first project to learn both Python and the inner workings of a chess engine and wanted to have some input on syntax, code efficiency and any tips in general on improving it before moving on with the project. My goal is to train a neural-network and use as a evaluation function down the line.

As of now it searches to a depth of 5 in seconds and to a depth 6 within a minute. Without evaluating the position it searches roughly 150 000 nodes/sec on my end.

What I have implemented so far:

- Bitboard representation of the state of the game.
- Precalculated look up tables for sliding piece attacks (rook, queen, bishop).
- Simple evaluation function as described here: https://www.chessprogramming.org/Simplified_Evaluation_Function
- minmax search with alpha-beta pruning and a simple sort of moves to cause more cut-offs.

What I will implement in the future:

- Iterative deepening
- Transposition tables
- Killer move heuristics

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon Aug 24 10:35:01 2020

@author: Grim Kalman
"""

"""
Open pre-calculated masks to avoid unnecessary calculations and facilitate
table lookup instead of on the spot calculations for speed. The attack masks
was calculated using the o-2s trick and the idea to store the masks in
dictionaries within a dictionary was taken from:
"Avoiding rotated bitboards with direct lookup" (S. Tannous, 2007).
"""

with open("file_mask_table.txt", "r") as file:
    fmt = eval(file.read())
    file.close()
with open("rank_mask_table.txt", "r") as file:
    rmt = eval(file.read())
    file.close()
with open("diagonal_mask_table.txt", "r") as file:
    dmt = eval(file.read())
    file.close()
with open("anti_diagonal_mask_table.txt", "r") as file:
    admt = eval(file.read())
    file.close()
with open("bitboard_to_pos.txt", "r") as file:
    bitboard_to_pos = eval(file.read())
    file.close()
with open("file_attacks.txt", "r") as file:
    fa = eval(file.read())
    file.close()
with open("rank_attacks.txt", "r") as file:
    ra = eval(file.read())
    file.close()
with open("diagonal_attacks.txt", "r") as file:
    da = eval(file.read())
    file.close()
with open("anti_diagonal_attacks.txt", "r") as file:
    ada = eval(file.read())
    file.close()
with open("king_attacks.txt", "r") as file:
    king_attacks = eval(file.read())
    file.close()
with open("knight_attacks.txt", "r") as file:
    knight_attacks = eval(file.read())
    file.close()
with open("white_pawn_attacks.txt", "r") as file:
    white_pawn_attacks = eval(file.read())
    file.close()
with open("black_pawn_attacks.txt", "r") as file:
    black_pawn_attacks = eval(file.read())
    file.close()
with open("piece_value_table.txt", "r") as file:
    pst = eval(file.read())
    file.close()

pieces = ["P", "R", "N", "B", "Q", "K", "p", "r", "n", "b", "q", "k"]

rows = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"]

cols = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]


class Game_State:
    """Class that represents the state of the chessboard."""

    def __init__(self):
        self.white_to_move = True
        self.bitboards = [0xFF00,               # 0 : white pawns
                          0x81,                 # 1 : white rooks
                          0x42,                 # 2 : white knights
                          0x24,                 # 3 : white bishops
                          0x10,                 # 4 : white queen
                          0x8,                  # 5 : white king
                          0xFF000000000000,     # 6 : black pawns
                          0x8100000000000000,   # 7 : black rooks
                          0x4200000000000000,   # 8 : black knights
                          0x2400000000000000,   # 9 : black bishops
                          0x1000000000000000,  # 10 : black queen
                          0x800000000000000,   # 11 : black king
                          0x000000000000FFFF,  # 12 : white pieces
                          0xFFFF000000000000,  # 13 : black pieces
                          0xFFFF00000000FFFF,  # 14 : all pieces
                          0,                   # 15 : en passant
                          0x8900000000000089   # 16 : castle rights
                          ]
        self.score = 0
        self.tp = {}
        self.history = []

    def load_FEN(self, string):
        """Load a position from a FEN-string."""
        self.bitboards = [0 for bitboards in self.bitboards]
        fen = string.split(" ")
        pos = fen[0].split("/")

        for row, rank in enumerate(pos):
            char = list(rank)
            col = 0
            for item in char:
                if item.isnumeric():
                    col += int(item)
                else:
                    self.bitboards[pieces.index(item)] += (2**(8*(7 - row) +
                                                               (7 - col)))
                    col += 1

        self.bitboards[12] = (self.bitboards[0] | self.bitboards[1] |
                              self.bitboards[2] | self.bitboards[3] |
                              self.bitboards[4] | self.bitboards[5])
        self.bitboards[13] = (self.bitboards[6] | self.bitboards[7] |
                              self.bitboards[8] | self.bitboards[9] |
                              self.bitboards[10] | self.bitboards[11])
        self.bitboards[14] = self.bitboards[12] | self.bitboards[13]
        self.bitboards[16] |= 0x9 if "K" in list(fen[2]) else 0
        self.bitboards[16] |= 0x88 if "Q" in list(fen[2]) else 0
        self.bitboards[16] |= 0x900000000000000 if "k" in list(fen[2]) else 0
        self.bitboards[16] |= 0x8800000000000000 if "q" in list(fen[2]) else 0

        if fen[1] == "w":
            self.white_to_move = True
            if fen[3] == '-':
                self.bitboards[15] = 0
            else:
                self.bitboards[15] = (2**(8*(rows.index(list(fen[3])[1]) - 1) +
                                          (7 - cols.index(list(fen[3])[0]))))
        else:
            self.white_to_move = False
            if fen[3] == '-':
                self.bitboards[15] = 0
            else:
                self.bitboards[15] = (2**(8*(rows.index(list(fen[3])[1]) + 1) +
                                          (7 - cols.index(list(fen[3])[0]))))

    def print_board(self):
        """Print a ASCII representation of the board in the console."""
        chessBoard = ["." for i in range(64)]
        for i in range(12):
            board = "{:064b}".format(self.bitboards[i])
            for y in range(8):
                for x in range(8):
                    if board[8 * y + x] == "1":
                        chessBoard[8 * y + x] = pieces[i]
        for i in range(8):
            print(str(8 - i), " ".join(chessBoard[8*i:8*(i + 1)]))
        print("  a b c d e f g h")

    def generate_moves(self):
        """Generate all pseudo-legal moves."""
        if self.white_to_move:
            return (king_moves(self, self.bitboards[14], self.bitboards[16],
                               self.bitboards[12], self.bitboards[5]) +
                    queen_moves(self.bitboards[14], self.bitboards[12],
                                self.bitboards[4]) +
                    rook_moves(self.bitboards[14], self.bitboards[12],
                               self.bitboards[1]) +
                    bishop_moves(self.bitboards[14], self.bitboards[12],
                                 self.bitboards[3]) +
                    knight_moves(self.bitboards[12], self.bitboards[2]) +
                    white_pawn_moves(self.bitboards[15], self.bitboards[13],
                                     self.bitboards[14], self.bitboards[0]))
        else:
            return (king_moves(self, self.bitboards[14], self.bitboards[16],
                               self.bitboards[13], self.bitboards[11]) +
                    queen_moves(self.bitboards[14], self.bitboards[13],
                                self.bitboards[10]) +
                    rook_moves(self.bitboards[14], self.bitboards[13],
                               self.bitboards[7]) +
                    bishop_moves(self.bitboards[14], self.bitboards[13],
                                 self.bitboards[9]) +
                    knight_moves(self.bitboards[13], self.bitboards[8]) +
                    black_pawn_moves(self.bitboards[15], self.bitboards[12],
                                     self.bitboards[14], self.bitboards[6]))

    def move(self, move):
        """Update the game state given a move.

        :param move: string representing a move, eg. 'e2e4'.
        """
        self.tp.clear()
        from_col, from_row, to_col, to_row = list(move)
        from_sq = 2**((7 - cols.index(from_col)) + 8*rows.index(from_row))
        to_sq = 2**((7 - cols.index(to_col)) + 8*rows.index(to_row))

        if self.white_to_move:
            for i in range(6):
                if from_sq & self.bitboards[i] != 0:
                    piece = i
                    break
        else:
            for i in range(6, 12):
                if from_sq & self.bitboards[i] != 0:
                    piece = i - 6
                    break

        self.make_move((from_sq, to_sq, piece))
        self.print_board()
        self.make_move(self.alpha_beta(6, -float('Inf'), float('Inf'))[1])
        print()
        self.print_board()

    def make_move(self, move):
        """Update the game state given a move.

        :param move: (from, to, piece) tuple. Eg. a pawn move from e2 to e4
                      would be written as: (2048, 134217728, 0).
        """
        self.history.append((self.white_to_move, self.bitboards[:],
                             self.score))
        move_from, move_to, piece = move

        if self.white_to_move:
            self.bitboards[piece] += move_to - move_from
            self.bitboards[12] += move_to - move_from
            self.score += (pst.get(piece).get(move_to) -
                           pst.get(piece).get(move_from))
            if (self.bitboards[13] & move_to):
                for i in range(6, 12):
                    if (self.bitboards[i] & move_to):
                        self.bitboards[i] -= move_to
                        self.bitboards[13] -= move_to
                        self.bitboards[15] = 0
                        self.score += pst.get(i).get(move_to)
                        break
            if piece == 0:
                if (move_from << 16) == move_to:
                    self.bitboards[15] = move_to
                elif move_to == self.bitboards[15]:
                    self.bitboards[6] -= move_to >> 8
                    self.bitboards[13] -= move_to >> 8
                    self.bitboards[15] = 0
                elif move_to & 0xff00000000000000 != 0:
                    self.bitboards[0] -= move_to
                    self.bitboards[4] += move_to
                else:
                    self.bitboards[15] = 0
            elif piece == 5:
                if move_from >> 2 == move_to:
                    self.bitboards[1] += (move_from >> 1) - (move_to >> 1)
                    self.bitboards[12] += (move_from >> 1) - (move_to >> 1)
                elif move_from << 2 == move_to:
                    self.bitboards[1] += (move_from << 1) - (move_to << 2)
                    self.bitboards[12] += (move_from << 1) - (move_to << 2)
                else:
                    self.bitboards[15] = 0
            else:
                self.bitboards[15] = 0
            self.white_to_move = False
        else:
            self.bitboards[piece + 6] += move_to - move_from
            self.bitboards[13] += move_to - move_from
            self.score -= (pst.get(piece + 6).get(move_to) -
                           pst.get(piece + 6).get(move_from))
            if (self.bitboards[12] & move_to):
                for i in range(6):
                    if (self.bitboards[i] & move_to):
                        self.bitboards[i] -= move_to
                        self.bitboards[12] -= move_to
                        self.bitboards[15] = 0
                        self.score -= pst.get(i).get(move_to)
                        break
            if piece == 0:
                if (move_from >> 16) == move_to:
                    self.bitboards[15] = move_to
                elif move_to == self.bitboards[15]:
                    self.bitboards[0] -= move_to << 8
                    self.bitboards[12] -= move_to << 8
                    self.bitboards[15] = 0
                elif move_to & 0xff != 0:
                    self.bitboards[6] -= move_to
                    self.bitboards[10] += move_to
                else:
                    self.bitboards[15] = 0
            elif piece == 5:
                if move_from >> 2 == move_to:
                    self.bitboards[7] += (move_from >> 1) - (move_to >> 1)
                    self.bitboards[13] += (move_from >> 1) - (move_to >> 1)
                elif move_from << 2 == move_to:
                    self.bitboards[7] += (move_from << 1) - (move_to << 2)
                    self.bitboards[13] += (move_from >> 1) - (move_to >> 1)
                else:
                    self.bitboards[15] = 0
            else:
                self.bitboards[15] = 0
            self.white_to_move = True

        self.bitboards[14] = self.bitboards[12] | self.bitboards[13]
        self.bitboards[16] = ((move_from & self.bitboards[16]) ^
                              self.bitboards[16])
        self.bitboards[16] = ((move_to & self.bitboards[16]) ^
                              self.bitboards[16])

    def undo_move(self):
        """Undo the previous move."""
        self.white_to_move, self.bitboards, self.score = self.history.pop()

    def is_check(self):
        """Determine if the king is in check.

        :return: bitboard containing all attacking pieces or 1 if the king is
                 taken.
        """
        if self.white_to_move and self.bitboards[5] != 0:
            (col, row), (diag, adiag) = bitboard_to_pos.get(self.bitboards[11])
            return ((self.bitboards[4] | self.bitboards[3]) & (da.get(self.bitboards[11]).get(self.bitboards[14] & dmt[diag]) | ada.get(self.bitboards[11]).get(self.bitboards[14] & admt[adiag]))) | ((self.bitboards[4] | self.bitboards[1]) & (ra.get(self.bitboards[11]).get(self.bitboards[14] & rmt[row]) | fa.get(self.bitboards[11]).get(self.bitboards[14] & fmt[col]))) | (self.bitboards[2] & knight_attacks.get(self.bitboards[11])) | (self.bitboards[0] & black_pawn_attacks.get(self.bitboards[11])) | (self.bitboards[5] & king_attacks.get(self.bitboards[11]))
        elif not self.white_to_move and self.bitboards[11] != 0:
            (col, row), (diag, adiag) = bitboard_to_pos.get(self.bitboards[5])
            return ((self.bitboards[10] | self.bitboards[9]) & (da.get(self.bitboards[5]).get(self.bitboards[14] & dmt[diag]) | ada.get(self.bitboards[5]).get(self.bitboards[14] & admt[adiag]))) | ((self.bitboards[10] | self.bitboards[7]) & (ra.get(self.bitboards[5]).get(self.bitboards[14] & rmt[row]) | fa.get(self.bitboards[5]).get(self.bitboards[14] & fmt[col]))) | (self.bitboards[8] & knight_attacks.get(self.bitboards[5])) | (self.bitboards[6] & white_pawn_attacks.get(self.bitboards[5])) | (self.bitboards[11] & king_attacks.get(self.bitboards[5]))
        else:
            return 1

    def perft(self, depth):
        """Traverse the game tree, mainly for debugging purposes."""
        if depth > 0:
            nodes = 0
            for move in self.generate_moves():
                self.make_move(move)
                if not self.is_check():
                    nodes += self.perft(depth - 1)
                self.undo_move()
            return nodes
        else:
            return 1

    def alpha_beta(self, depth, alpha, beta):
        """Preform a alpha-beta search to the desired depth."""
        if depth == 0:
            return self.score, None
        else:
            best_move = None
            if self.white_to_move:
                move_list = self.sort(self.generate_moves(), -1)
                for move in move_list:
                    self.make_move(move[1])
                    if not self.is_check():
                        score = self.alpha_beta(depth - 1, alpha, beta)[0]
                        if score > alpha:  # white maximizes her score
                            alpha = score
                            best_move = move[1]
                            self.undo_move()
                            if alpha >= beta:  # alpha-beta cutoff
                                break
                        else:
                            self.undo_move()
                    else:
                        self.undo_move()
                return (alpha, best_move)
            else:
                move_list = self.sort(self.generate_moves(), 1)
                for move in move_list:
                    self.make_move(move[1])
                    if not self.is_check():
                        score = self.alpha_beta(depth - 1, alpha, beta)[0]
                        if score < beta:  # black minimizes his score
                            beta = score
                            best_move = move[1]
                            self.undo_move()
                            if alpha >= beta:  # alpha-beta cutoff
                                break
                        else:
                            self.undo_move()
                    else:
                        self.undo_move()
                return (beta, best_move)

    def sort(self, move_list, turn):
        """
        Sort the moves in the list based on static-evaluation in next node.

        :param move_list: list of pseduo-legal moves.
        :param turn: -1 for white and 1 for black.
        :return: sorted list.
        """
        sorted_list = []
        for move in move_list:
            self.make_move(move)
            sorted_list.append((self.score, move))
            self.undo_move()
        return sorted(sorted_list, key=lambda item: turn*item[0])

    def generate_hash(self):
        """Generate a hash-key from the position."""
        return hash(tuple(self.bitboards)) + int(self.white_to_move)


def is_attacked(gs, s):
    """
    Determine if the square is attacked by enemy pieces.

    :param gs: a Game_State class object.
    :param s: bitboard with the square to be checked set to 1.
    :return: bitboard containing all attacking pieces.
    """
    (col, row), (diag, adiag) = bitboard_to_pos.get(s)

    if gs.white_to_move:
        return (((gs.bitboards[10] | gs.bitboards[9]) &
                (da.get(s).get(gs.bitboards[14] & dmt[diag]) |
                 ada.get(s).get(gs.bitboards[14] & admt[adiag]))) |
                ((gs.bitboards[10] | gs.bitboards[7]) &
                 (ra.get(s).get(gs.bitboards[14] & rmt[row]) |
                  fa.get(s).get(gs.bitboards[14] & fmt[col]))) |
                (gs.bitboards[8] & knight_attacks.get(s)) |
                (gs.bitboards[6] & white_pawn_attacks.get(s)) |
                (gs.bitboards[11] & king_attacks.get(s)))
    else:
        return (((gs.bitboards[4] | gs.bitboards[3]) &
                 (da.get(s).get(gs.bitboards[14] & dmt[diag]) |
                  ada.get(s).get(gs.bitboards[14] & admt[adiag]))) |
                ((gs.bitboards[4] | gs.bitboards[1]) &
                 (ra.get(s).get(gs.bitboards[14] & rmt[row]) |
                  fa.get(s).get(gs.bitboards[14] & fmt[col]))) |
                (gs.bitboards[2] & knight_attacks.get(s)) |
                (gs.bitboards[0] & black_pawn_attacks.get(s)) |
                (gs.bitboards[5] & king_attacks.get(s)))


def white_pawn_moves(ep, bp, o, s):
    """
    Generate a bitboard of available pawn moves for white.

    :param ep: bitboard containing the available en passant captures.
    :param bp: bitboard containing all black pieces.
    :param o: bitboard containing all pieces.
    :param s: bitboard of all white pawns.
    :return: list of pseudo-legal moves.
    """
    move_list = []
    clippedL = s & 0x7F7F7F7F7F7F7F7F
    clippedR = s & 0xFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFE
    push = (s << 8) & (o ^ 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
    double_push = ((push & 0x0000000000FF0000) << 8) & (o ^ 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
    captures = (clippedL << 9 & bp | clippedR << 7 & bp |
                (clippedL << 1 & ep) << 8 | (clippedR >> 1 & ep) << 8)

    move_to = push & -push
    while move_to > 0:
        move_list.append((move_to >> 8, move_to, 0))
        push = push & (push - 1)
        move_to = push & -push

    move_to = double_push & -double_push
    while move_to > 0:
        move_list.append((move_to >> 16, move_to, 0))
        double_push = double_push & (double_push - 1)
        move_to = double_push & -double_push

    move_to = captures & -captures
    while move_to > 0:
        source = s & black_pawn_attacks.get(move_to)
        move_from = source & -source
        while move_from > 0:
            move_list.append((move_from, move_to, 0))
            source = source & (source - 1)
            move_from = source & -source
        captures = captures & (captures - 1)
        move_to = captures & -captures

    return move_list


def black_pawn_moves(ep, wp, o, s):
    """
    Generate a bitboard of available pawn moves for black.

    :param ep: bitboard containing the available en passant captures.
    :param wp: bitboard containing all white pieces.
    :param o: bitboard containing all pieces.
    :param s: bitboard of all white pawns.
    :return: list of pseudo-legal moves.
    """
    move_list = []
    clippedL = s & 0x7F7F7F7F7F7F7F7F
    clippedR = s & 0xFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFE
    push = (s >> 8) & (o ^ 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
    double_push = ((push & 0xFF0000000000) >> 8) & (o ^ 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
    captures = (clippedR >> 9 & wp | clippedL >> 7 & wp |
                (clippedL << 1 & ep) >> 8 | (clippedR >> 1 & ep) >> 8)

    move_to = push & -push
    while move_to > 0:
        move_list.append((move_to << 8, move_to, 0))
        push = push & (push - 1)
        move_to = push & -push

    move_to = double_push & -double_push
    while move_to > 0:
        move_list.append((move_to << 16, move_to, 0))
        double_push = double_push & (double_push - 1)
        move_to = double_push & -double_push

    move_to = captures & -captures
    while move_to > 0:
        source = s & white_pawn_attacks.get(move_to)
        move_from = source & -source
        while move_from > 0:
            move_list.append((move_from, move_to, 0))
            source = source & (source - 1)
            move_from = source & -source
        captures = captures & (captures - 1)
        move_to = captures & -captures

    return move_list


def king_moves(gs, o, c, b, s):
    """
    Generate a bitboard of available king moves.

    :param gs: a Game_State class object.
    :param o: bitboard containing all pieces.
    :param c: biboard containing castle relevant pieces that has not moved.
    :param b: bitboard of all pieces of own color.
    :param s: bitboard of the king
    :return: list of pseudo-legal moves.
    """
    move_list = []
    moves = king_attacks.get(s) & (b ^ 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)

    move_to = moves & -moves
    while move_to > 0:
        move_list.append((s, move_to, 5))
        moves = moves & (moves - 1)
        move_to = moves & -moves

    if s | c == c and s >> 3 & c != 0 and s >> 1 & o == 0 and s >> 2 & o == 0:
        if not is_attacked(gs, s) and not is_attacked(gs, s >> 1):
            move_list.append((s, s >> 2, 5))  # O-O

    if (s | c == c and s << 4 & c != 0 and s << 1 & o == 0 and
        s << 2 & o == 0 and s << 3 & o == 0):
        if not is_attacked(gs, s) and not is_attacked(gs, s << 1):
            move_list.append((s, s << 2, 5))  # O-O-O

    return move_list


def knight_moves(b, s):
    """Generate a bitboard of available knight moves.

    :param b: bitboard of all pieces of own color.
    :param s: bitboard of the king
    :return: list of pseudo-legal moves.
    """
    move_list = []

    move_from = s & -s
    while move_from > 0:
        moves = knight_attacks.get(move_from) & (b ^ 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)

        move_to = moves & -moves
        while move_to > 0:
            move_list.append((move_from, move_to, 2))
            moves = moves & (moves - 1)
            move_to = moves & -moves
        s = s & (s - 1)
        move_from = s & -s

    return move_list


def rook_moves(o, b, s):
    """Generate a bitboard of available rook moves.

    :param o: bitboard of all pieces
    :param b: bitboard of all pieces of own color.
    :param s: bitboard of the king
    :return: list of pseudo-legal moves.
    """
    move_list = []

    move_from = s & -s
    while move_from > 0:
        (col, row), (_) = bitboard_to_pos.get(move_from)
        moves = ((ra.get(move_from).get(o & rmt[row]) |
                 fa.get(move_from).get(o & fmt[col])) &
                 (b ^ 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF))

        move_to = moves & -moves
        while move_to > 0:
            move_list.append((move_from, move_to, 1))
            moves = moves & (moves - 1)
            move_to = moves & -moves
        s = s & (s - 1)
        move_from = s & -s

    return move_list


def bishop_moves(o, b, s):
    """Generate a bitboard of available bishop moves.

    :param o: bitboard of all pieces
    :param b: bitboard of all pieces of own color.
    :param s: bitboard of the king
    :return: list of pseudo-legal moves.
    """
    move_list = []

    move_from = s & -s
    while move_from > 0:
        (_), (diag, adiag) = bitboard_to_pos.get(move_from)
        moves = ((da.get(move_from).get(o & dmt[diag]) |
                  ada.get(move_from).get(o & admt[adiag])) &
                 (b ^ 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF))
        move_to = moves & -moves

        while move_to > 0:
            move_list.append((move_from, move_to, 3))
            moves = moves & (moves - 1)
            move_to = moves & -moves
        s = s & (s - 1)
        move_from = s & -s

    return move_list


def queen_moves(o, b, s):
    """Generate a bitboard of available queen moves.

    :param o: bitboard of all pieces
    :param b: bitboard of all pieces of own color.
    :param s: bitboard of the king
    :return: list of pseudo-legal moves.
    """
    move_list = []
    move_from = s & -s

    while move_from > 0:
        (col, row), (diag, adiag) = bitboard_to_pos.get(move_from)
        moves = ((ra.get(move_from).get(o & rmt[row]) |
                 fa.get(move_from).get(o & fmt[col]) |
                 da.get(move_from).get(o & dmt[diag]) |
                 ada.get(move_from).get(o & admt[adiag])) &
                 (b ^ 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF))
        move_to = moves & -moves

        while move_to > 0:
            move_list.append((s, move_to, 4))
            moves = moves & (moves - 1)
            move_to = moves & -moves
        s = s & (s - 1)
        move_from = s & -s

    return move_list


def print_bitboard(bitboard):
    """Print a bitboard, mainly for development purposes."""
    board = "{:064b}".format(bitboard)
    for y in range(8):
        for x in range(8):
            print(board[8 * y + x] + " ", end="")
        print("")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    game = Game_State()
    game.print_board()
    while abs(game.score) < 15000:
        print('Input move:')
        move = input()
        game.move(move)
    print("Game over!")

    a = Game_State()
```

the .txt files needed in order for the script to run can be found here: https://github.com/grimkalman/ChessBOT